# Time complexity with log in a loop

Tags: c++, algorithm, loops, time-complexity

What is the complexity of a loop which goes the following?

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < log(i); j++)
    {
        // Do something
    }
}
```

According to me, the inner loop will be running `log(1)+log(2)+log(3)+...+log(n)` times, so how do I calculate its complexity?

Comment: _"According to me"_ Always found this phrase amusing. We typically use "according to" to announce a third-party authority we used to arrive at a conclusion. You can't use yourself as a third-party authority.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit According to me you can.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So, you have a sum `log(1) + log(2) + log(3) + ... + log(n) = log(n!)`. By using [Stirling's approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling's_approximation) and the fact that `ln(x) = log(x) / log(e)` one can get

```
log(n!) = log(e) * ln(n!) = log(e) (n ln(n) - n + O(ln(n)))
```

which gives the same complexity `O(n ln(n))` as in the other answer (with slightly better understanding of the constants involved).

Comment: Nice qualitative analysis -- `\sum_{i=1}^{n} log(i) => log(n!)` which allows us to use Stirling's approximation good catch!

Answer (score 8):

Without doing this in a formal manner, such complexity calculations can be "guessed" using integrals. The integrand is the complexity of `do_something`, which is assumed to be `O(1)`, and combined with the interval of `log N`, this then becomes `log N` for the inner loop. Combined with the outer loop, the overall complexity is `O(N log N)`. So between linear and quadratic.

Note: this assumes that "do something" is `O(1)` (in terms of `N`, it could be of a very high constant of course).

Comment: Multiply that by the complexity of "do something".

Comment: How can the complexity be worse than that of a basic two-dimensional loop over `n^2`? How can it be worse than `n*log n` for that matter? Honestly asking - it's been a while since I've studied this formally. But "between quadratic and cubic" for this intuitively seems wrong to me?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit duh, you are right, I messed up, fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

Let’s start with `log(1)+log(2)+log(3)+...+log(n)`.

Roughly half of the elements of this sum are greater than or equal to `log(n/2) = log(n) - log(2)`. Hence the lower bound of this sum is `n / 2 * (log(n) - log(2)) = Omega(nlog(n))`. To get the upper bound, simply multiply `n` by the largest element which is `log(n)`, hence `O(nlog(n))`.